# Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j

Tags: java, .net, logging, log4net, log4j

I would like to set the log file name for a log4j and log4net appender to have the current date.  We are doing Daily rollovers but the current log file does not have a date.  The log file name format would be

```
logname.2008-10-10.log
```

Anyone know the best way for me to do this?

edit:  I forgot to mention that we would want to do this in log4net as well.  Plus any solution would need to be usable in JBoss.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

DailyRollingFileAppender is what you exactly searching for.

```
<appender name="roll" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="application.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: Won't this simply create a log file called "application.log" and only place the datepattern in the rolled log files?

Comment: As a result you will get a separate log file for each day. But the todays log file will be named as application.log, without a date. And it's ok in most cases.

Comment: Two comments on "DatePattern":
- I use ".yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g" to get the same extension for all log files.
- The backslash before g is needed (at least for log4net) to prevent .Net applying the predefined "g" format.

Comment: @gyrolf, applying the format you mention, do your logs end up as mylog.log.yyyy-MM-dd.log? Or are you somehow removing the previous extension?

Comment: From log4j docs: DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss.(http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). you should really follow @shinds answer

Comment: This is not what the OP asks for. This solution will not have the current date.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon I've used log4j with a log4j.properties file like so: `log4j.appender.roll.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'` and yes this results in a file name like application.log.2016-01-25.log

Answer (score 49):

Using log4j.properties file, and including [apache-log4j-extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) 1.1 in my POM with log4j 1.2.16

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/logs/application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

Comment: ^---^ Pro level: 99
`log4j.appender.out.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss} cron-script-x/out.log

log4j.appender.err.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss} cron-script-x/err.log`

Comment: As of right now, the download mirrors links are all broken. You can still find the library in the archive repository: http://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/companions/extras

Comment: log4j.appender..DatePattern=yyyy-MM-dd will do the trick. File name will roll every day and no need for additional dependency

Answer (score 12):

I'm 99% sure that RollingFileAppender/DailyRollingFileAppender, while it gives you the date-rolling functionality you want, doesn't have any way to specify that the current log file should use the `DatePattern` as well.

You might just be able to simply subclass RollingFileAppender (or DailyRollingFileAppender, I forget which is which in log4net) and modify the naming logic.

Answer (score 11):

I have created an appender that will do that.  http://stauffer.james.googlepages.com/DateFormatFileAppender.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) The Apache Software Foundation. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is published under the terms of the Apache Software
 * License version 1.1, a copy of which has been included with this
 * distribution in the LICENSE.txt file.  */

package sps.log.log4j;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.log4j.*;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

/**
 * DateFormatFileAppender is a log4j Appender and extends 
 * {@link FileAppender} so each log is 
 * named based on a date format defined in the File property.
 *
 * Sample File: 'logs/'yyyy/MM-MMM/dd-EEE/HH-mm-ss-S'.log'
 * Makes a file like: logs/2004/04-Apr/13-Tue/09-45-15-937.log
 * @author James Stauffer
 */
public class DateFormatFileAppender extends FileAppender {

  /**
   * The default constructor does nothing.
   */
  public DateFormatFileAppender() {
  }

  /**
   * Instantiate a <code>DailyRollingFileAppender</code> and open the
   * file designated by <code>filename</code>. The opened filename will
   * become the ouput destination for this appender.
   */
  public DateFormatFileAppender (Layout layout, String filename) throws IOException {
    super(layout, filename, true);
  }

  private String fileBackup;//Saves the file pattern
  private boolean separate = false;

  public void setFile(String file) {
    super.setFile(file);
    this.fileBackup = getFile();
  }

  /**
   * If true each LoggingEvent causes that file to close and open.
   * This is useful when the file is a pattern that would often
   * produce a different filename.
   */
  public void setSeparate(boolean separate) {
    this.separate = separate;
  }

  protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
    if(separate) {
        try {//First reset the file so each new log gets a new file.
            setFile(getFile(), getAppend(), getBufferedIO(), getBufferSize());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            LogLog.error("Unable to reset fileName.");
        }
    }
    super.subAppend(event);
  }


  public
  synchronized
  void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize)
                                                            throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fileBackup);
    String actualFileName = sdf.format(new Date());
    makeDirs(actualFileName);
    super.setFile(actualFileName, append, bufferedIO, bufferSize);
  }

  /**
   * Ensures that all of the directories for the given path exist.
   * Anything after the last / or \ is assumed to be a filename.
   */
  private void makeDirs (String path) {
    int indexSlash = path.lastIndexOf("/");
    int indexBackSlash = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
    int index = Math.max(indexSlash, indexBackSlash);
    if(index > 0) {
        String dirs = path.substring(0, index);
//        LogLog.debug("Making " + dirs);
        File dir = new File(dirs);
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            boolean success = dir.mkdirs();
            if(!success) {
                LogLog.error("Unable to create directories for " + dirs);
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if it is possible in Java, but in .NET the property StaticLogFileName on RollingFileAppender gives you what you want. The default is true.

```
<staticLogFileName value="false"/>
```

Full config:

```xml
<appender name="DefaultFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="application"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd&quot;.log&quot;" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

`&quot;.log&quot;` is for not letting the dateformat recognice the global date pattern 'g' in log.

Comment: Just for clarification: Are the HTML entities `&quot` in `yyyy-MM-dd&quot;.log&quot;` meant to be there, instead of `'`?

Answer (score 2):

this example will be creating logger for each minute, if you want to change for each day change the `DatePattern` value.

```
<appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
   <param name="File" value="./applogs/logger.log" />
   <param name="Append" value="true" />
   <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"/>
   <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="fileNamePattern" value="./applogs/logger_%d{ddMMMyyyy HH:mm:ss}.log"/>
      <param name="rollOver" value="TRUE"/>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ddMMMyyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}^[%X{l4j_mdc_key}]^[%c{1}]^ %-5p %m%n" />
   </layout>
</appender>
<root>
   <level value="info" />
   <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a response to the two answers which mention DailyRollingFileAppender (sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment on them directly, and I think this needs to be mentioned), I would warn that unfortunately the developers of that class have documented that it exhibits synchronization and data loss, and recommend that alternatives should be pursued for new deployments.

[DailyRollingFileAppender JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can set [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) dynamically

```
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();           
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"logname."+new Date().toLocaleString(),false);
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

Comment: Be carefull with the slashes "/" in the file name. I would rather user: `"logname"+new Date().format("yyyy-mm-dd-hh-MM")+".log"`

Comment: This will create new log file only on app start and will not cut your logs to files by date

Answer (score 1):

just use TimeBasedRollingPolicy and don't use param name="File"

```
  <appender name="pdi-execution-appender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">   
        <!-- The active file to log to; this example is for Pentaho Server.-->
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- See javadoc for TimeBasedRollingPolicy -->
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/ETL-LogFile.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value='%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %m'/>
        </layout>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use `DailyRollingFileAppender` like @gedevan suggested, you will still get `logname.log.2008-10-10` (After a day, because the previous day log will get archived and the date will be concatenated to it's filename).

So if you want *.log* at the end, you'll have to do it like this on the `DatePattern`:

`log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm'.log'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically like so:

```
        String dateFile = LocalDate.now().toString() + ".log";
        Enumeration enm = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
        Appender appender = null;
        while(enm.hasMoreElements()){
            appender = (Appender)enm.nextElement();
            String c = appender.getClass().toString();
            if(c.contains("FileAppender")){
                String f = ((FileAppender)appender).getFile();
                ((FileAppender)appender).setFile(f+dateFile);
                System.out.println("From:"+f+" to:"+dateFile);
            }
        }
```