# Creating daily logs with Log4j?

Tags: java, configuration, logging, log4j

What configuration values are needed to setup Log4j to use the following pattern?
**MyApp-Mon.log

MyApp-Tue.log

MyApp-Wed.log

Etc**

With each file containing the days log.

This sounds easy enough to do with Log4j's DailyRollingFileAppender but I am having trouble.
Here is my current config;

```
<appender name="daily-file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'EE'.log'"/>
    <param name="file" value="MyApp"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy} %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I based this config on [this](http://mhashem.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/log4j-roll-log-file-daily/) blog post, but it is not behaving in the way he describes. The log is being created as MyApp with no extension.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Your `DatePattern` value looks pretty odd, you have several single quotes in there.

Comment: @skaffman, That is intentional, I took it from that blog and from another source I looked at a while ago. I assumed it was to separate the Java date format from the text appended to the log filename.

Comment: I've edited the question down to its simplest form to reduce confusion.

Comment: @James: I think that's a bit of a step backwards, now we have *less* information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I based this config on this blog post, but it is not behaving in the way he describes. The log is being created as MyApp with no extension.

This is what you told Log4J to do with this line:

```
<param name="file" value="MyApp"/>
```

Log4J uses the value of this option as log file name and the pattern is only applied when the roll over occurs, as [documented](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html):

> For example, if the File option is set
>   to /foo/bar.log and the DatePattern
>   set to '.'yyyy-MM-dd, on 2001-02-16 at
>   midnight, the logging file
>   /foo/bar.log will be copied to
>   /foo/bar.log.2001-02-16 and logging
>   for 2001-02-17 will continue in
>   /foo/bar.log until it rolls over the
>   next day.

So everything looks normal to me.

To obtain the desired behavior, you could write your own `Appender`. It looks like James Stauffer did something very similar (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j/192744#192744)) but he extends `FileAppender`. It should be easy to adapt his work for a `DailyRollingFileAppender` subclass though.

Comment: @Pascal, I am going to clarify my question a little. How would I get the intended behavior that I am looking for? I am trying to shoe horn these logs in a legacy log viewer that department has.

Answer (score 0):

the current logfile is named MyApp, then tomorrow it will be renamed by Myapp-yesterday and so on

but the current log has always the default name.

Comment: Anyway to make it append the datepattern by default?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the JavaDocs for the DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html), all the examples they set out have specific, numeric date patterns, not day-name patterns.  Have you tried to see if using one of their examples works?  If so, and yours doesn't, then I'd assume that the DailyRollingFileAppender doesn't support the use of a date pattern containing 'E' (the day of the week).

Comment: Just tested it using a minute pattern, yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-EE, EE resolves to the date name.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment to Pascal's answer:

Would a `ln -s MyApp.log MyApp-NOW.log` work? Your legacy log viewer would show MyApp-NOW.log via the symbolic link and log4j can roll-over MyApp.log to MyApp-TUE.log at midnight.

Comment: @rsp, we are using windows on our servers, so the symbolic link solution is not feasible.

Comment: You might be able to use a windows shortcut? Also if you have Vista or newer I see on msdn that windows supports symlinks via the mklink command. (Can't test it as I have XP)