# Appending current time to a new log file each time log4j is initialized

Tags: java, log4j

Every single time I run my app, I want a new log file to be generated with the time stamp.  Something like **MyFile-4Nov2010-132122.log**.

I've seen the use of the [DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j) however I want it to roll each and every time as opposed to just daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass [`FileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) or [`DailyRollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) to create a new file when the appender is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks Catchwa.  Actually easier than I thought to create my own with a custom file name by overriding "void setFile(String);"

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure the XML config file as below:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="./logs/message"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <!-- Rollover at midnight each minute -->

  <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>-->
      <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>  
  </layout>
```