# Creating a log file with current time

Tags: c, logging, log4c

I am trying to do something similar to [Appending current time to a new log file each time log4j is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093382/appending-current-time-to-a-new-log-file-each-time-log4j-is-initialized).
I am using **log4c** for logging. I would like to be able to create a new log file with each execution of the application. Is it possible to do this, by only modifying the log4crc config file.
All help will be greatly appreciated

ps: The tag I wanted to used is log4c, but it isn't there in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible via any config file. I had to modify the appender used to name the log file based on the current time. I used the functions `time()`, `localtime()` and `strftime()` to create the file name

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It is now fixed in the current release, but Ubuntu for example still ships an older version without this facility.

See [How to change log4c's default timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107982/how-to-change-log4cs-default-timezone)