# How to change log4c's default timezone?

Tags: timezone, log4c

I just installed log4c and log4c-devel on CentOS 6.x by yum.  All works fine except the log time, it's slow for 8 hours

Following is the output of my machine:

```
[rafael@localhost ~]$ date
Tue Jan 14 15:17:34 CST 2014
```

Following is the log produced by log4c:

```
20140114 07:17:34.453 DEBUG    GFXLog- CTimerManager::killTimer: time id-0x0000000198c4e0.
```

you see, slow for 8 hours.  I have setup my machine with correct time and timezone, and also keep ntpd running.  I think maybe i should setup log4c timezone, but I don't know how?  log4crc or code?  cannot find any document about that by google.

Comment: After digging into the source code, I have solved the issue. 

Just need to replace dated to dated_local in log4crc configure file.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but in Ubuntu 14.04 dated_local is not available because log4c is an older version. I wrote an update based on the latest log4c code which does not require modifying the supplied shared library.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/log4c/+bug/1314576

Comment: Including the explanations in your answer in addition to linking to the launchpad thread will make it even more useful (and syntax highlighting looks better on SO :) )