# How do you create log files in log4j per program execution?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, config

I am currently using the DailyRollingFileAppender Class in log4j to do daily log file appending but I want to have the log files separated in the following format:

```
DATA.log.<date>_<time>_<random_#>
```

This should be done once per program execution so I end up with something like...

```
DATA.log.2011-01-13_12-46-38_<26>
DATA.log.2011-01-13_12-46-38_<79>
DATA.log.2011-01-13_12-46-38_<590>
```

Where different log files from different environments can be pooled together.

Is there anyway to do this without extending the FileAppender Class? At least, is there a way to do:

```
DATA.log.<date>_<time>_<sequential_#>.log
```

Thanks

Edit: I am already using DailyRollingFileAppender to get something like DATA.log.2011-01-13. What I want to know how to do is get the log file to rollover after each program execution (or before each program execution) and add a random numeric string at the end.

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: Thanks Dave. Another question, I am trying to add a property to my class, i.e. log4j.appender.DATA.CustomProperty=value. How do I do this?

Comment: Nevermind... it's easy, I just didn't capitalize it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at : [Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)

EDIT : 
Add this class to your project, and use it as appender :

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender;

public class MyAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender {    
    @Override
    public void  setFile(String fileName) {
        if (fileName.indexOf("%rnd") >= 0) {
            Random r = new Random();
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("%rnd", Integer.toString(r.nextInt()));
        }
        super.setFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

Then just set your appender's filename to something like : filename.%rnd.log

```
log4j.appender.R=MyAppender.MyAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=.\\test.%rnd.log
```

Comment: I am already doing what the URL you posted says to do. What I want to do is add an additional random string at the end after each program execution so that I can keep track of multiple logs. I will edit my question for this.

Comment: And you can add some other new patterns as well easily. And us it across several projects

Answer (score 1):

In your code set a new environment property:

```
randomString = Long.toString(Math.abs((new Random()).nextLong()), Character.MAX_RADIX);
System.setProperty("randomString", randomString);
```

Then, in your log4j file use that variable using `${randomString}`.

Hope it helps.