# how to include date/time in log filename in log4j properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I want to create a log file for log4j using `FileAppender`.

For e.g if log file is : `/home/jj/socket/socket.log`

I want log as:

```
/home/jj/socket/socket_YYYYMMDDhhmm.log
```

or

```
/home/jj/socket/socket_YYYYMMDD.log
```

Comment: See this SO question and it's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j

Comment: I looked at it before asking this question. It basically suggests using: RollingFileAppender/DailyRollingFileAppender, which I cannot use in my use case.

Comment: Fine. Then set your own filename when opening FileAppender. You can create them programmatically, you know. And if creating FileAppender programmatically is no good, create your own subclass of it, and set the filename.