# log4j FileAppender using FileDatePatternConverter

Tags: date, log4j, design-patterns, fileappender

Trying to use a pattern for filename in config such as:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" class="org.apache.log4j.pattern.FileDatePatternConverter" value="logs/App-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p(%c{1}) %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}: %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

This does not what work.  What is correct syntax?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j