# RollingFileAppender to follow date and produce textfiles?

Tags: log4net

I got this:

```xml
<appender name="iOsClients_Error" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/errors/error_"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>                
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%newline%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline%newline%exception%newline%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

This will create a log file like: `error_20110801`

How can I get log4net to output text files or how can I get log4net to add the .txt file extension to these files?

I want this: `error_20110801.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to accomplish that:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/errors/error_%date{yyyyMMdd}.txt" />
```

They key here is to use the `PatternString`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/errors/error_%date{yyyyMMdd}.txt" />
```

is that if the server doesn't restart every day, the file will have the same date, so the same name. And the archived file will be like error_20130101.txt20130101 . 
The solution to this is here actually : [Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)