# Log file name to include current date in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

The question is a subset of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j).
I want a log file to be created everyday with the log file name format as follows:
 `downloadmanageryyyy-MM-dd.log`
Using `DailyRollingAppender`but the log file is not created at all.

My lo4j.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                         <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
   <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
   <appender name="InfoLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="downloadmanager.log"/>
       <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
       <param name="ConversionPattern" 
      value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>  
  </log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j

Comment: Had no option but to post this since the answer posted din't work for me!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DailyRollingFileAppender` shipping with log4j will not rename the log file until the first message is logged some time after midnight.

You may try to use `DatedFileAppender` , which can be download from [here](http://minaret.biz/tips/datedFileAppender.html).  Contrary to the `DailyRollingFileAppender` , it will create the log file whose filename always contains today's date.

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted.Thanks.