# Create log file with date using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm writing my log file using below code but it stores file as `QueryLog.log`. Am i missing something? Check my code of `log4j.properties` file

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j/QueryLog.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern= %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Links i used:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files

Comment: The first file will simply be named `log4j/QueryLog.log`. When your logs roll over from there, they will have the data appended to them. This is why it is a `RollingFileAppender`.

Comment: ohh. I got it now. he is expecting file to have date appended today itself.

Comment: @VickyThakor See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798794/log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j

Comment: @Vicky Your current date logs will always be stored in file without date appended to it. When day passes. your older file will be renamed to have yesterday's date appended to filename and new file will conatain current day's logs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is mentioned in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798794/log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j), the purpose of a `RollingFileAppender` is to automatically create a new log file at some defined interval. In the case of the `DailyRollingFileAppender`, that interval is 12:00 AM of each day.

What this means is that the first file created by log4j will have the file name you specified here:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j/QueryLog.log
```

And, from then forward, each day a new log file will be created with the date appended to it.

To always name the file with the date appended, you could use [`DatedFileAppender`](http://minaret.biz/tips/datedFileAppender.html) by Geoff Mottram

Comment: let me try `DatedFileAppender`

Answer (score 1):

This line sets the log file name, in your log4j properties you have:
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j/QueryLog.log

You can see the answer here
[Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)

Comment: Unless order of properties matters, it seems like what he's done should produce a file `log4j/QueryLog.log.2012-09-10-AM`

Comment: He want name to change everyday.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to log directly to a file with current active date/time such as XYZ.log.20150101.log instead of XYZ.log could be done by simply removing ActiveFileName property when using the rolling package org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender in the apache-log4j-extras 1.1 with log4j 1.2.x.

```
<appender name="defaultFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/application/custom-application-logger.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm}" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %-10t [%-40.40c] %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```