# How to create a log file with file name and current system date using log4j?

Tags: logging, log4j

I want a log file to be created with the file name and current system date using log4j. Can you guys please help me with log4j.properties code for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the existing questions will answer to yours ...

[Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/192456/1811730)

[Filename with date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629772/1811730)

[Create log file with date using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18719902/1811730)

[Log file name to include current date in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8798794/1811730)

Comment: I want a code with working log4j.properties code. But the examples are with the code added to context.xml

Comment: Properties for log4j can be defined by a properties file or by an XML file. both have advantage an inconvenient. but properties are same. You can use log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender http://stackoverflow.com/q/18719902/1811730