# log4j. Unique log-file name

Tags: java, log4j

How I can create a uniquely named log file using `log4j`?. When I used `Logback`, I can do it like this:

```
 <!-- current time formatted as "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss".  This value will be available to all 
    subsequent configuration elements. -->
<timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" />
```

and inside logger appender define file name pattern:

```
<file>${bySecond}.log</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no support for this feature in log4j 1.7 out of the box. But you can extend [`RollingFileAppender`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.java.html)'s `setFile` method by altering `fileName` parameter to support the time-based feature.

Answer (score 0):

the [`DailyRollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) appends the current date afer rolling over to the next file, so you get a unique name ending with the date of the log for every file.
Cite JavaDoc:

> For example, if the File option is set to /foo/bar.log and the
>   DatePattern set to '.'yyyy-MM-dd, on 2001-02-16 at midnight, the
>   logging file /foo/bar.log will be copied to /foo/bar.log.2001-02-16
>   and logging for 2001-02-17 will continue in /foo/bar.log until it
>   rolls over the next day.

add something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192548/1515052) to your properties XML file:

```
<appender name="roll" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="application.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```