# Create new log file daily using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I want to use Log4j in my java project, which configuration should I provide in
configuration file that every night at 12.00 am new file will generate and file
name should like - **output-log-of-MyProjectName-HostName-2013-Dec-10.txt**
name). My configuration  file is like that-

```
log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.FILE.File = ${log}/log.out    
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern = '.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
```

It is creating new file everyday but it appending date after file name.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you getting and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: Can you give an example of the file nameS (more than one) you are seeing, and what you want them to look like?

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

Comment: I just want my file name should start with current date, like output-log-2013-Dec-10.txt, Please help,

Comment: Log4J is appending date after its file name, so the extension of the file is changed, is it possible to append date before file extension. Generated file is logfile.out.2013-12-16-PM but I want like logfile.2013-12-16-PM.out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want DailyRollingFileAppender (geedubb links to the log4j docs about it)
[Here is example](http://blog.moes.as/2008/10/example-of-using-dailyrollingfileappend.html)

[Here is another stackoverflow question like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)