# In my java program , I want to make different log files for every day run of my batch program ( filenames ending with current date )

Tags: java, logging, log4j, batch-processing

This is my log4j.xml file . Tell me how should i change this , so that different log files are crated everyday and each file names ends with that days date .

```
<appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${logfilename}.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,SSS}  %5p [%t] %c [%M] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="Com.ReadExcelDemo">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
</logger>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new log file daily using log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618527/create-new-log-file-daily-using-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you surely

```
 PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
 String conversionPattern = "[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n";
 layout.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern);
 // creates daily rolling file appender
 DailyRollingFileAppender rollingAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
 rollingAppender.setFile(LOG_PATH+"my.report.log");
 rollingAppender.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
 rollingAppender.setLayout(layout);
 rollingAppender.activateOptions();
 // configures the root logger
 Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
 rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
 rootLogger.addAppender(rollingAppender);
 // creates a custom logger and log messages
 logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClassName.class);
 logger.info("Your Logger Ready");
```

Comment: This is  creating file with name 'my.report.log' . This is what  i gave :                    DailyRollingFileAppender rollingAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
rollingAppender       .setFile("./applogs/my.report.log");
        rollingAppender.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
        rollingAppender.setLayout(layout);
        rollingAppender.activateOptions();