# Generate daily log file using ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I switch the default logging Tomcat java.util.logging(JUL) to log4j. Currently I can generate one `stdout.log` file each time I start. Problem here is that I want generate my `stdout.log` file on daily basis without restarting my Tomcat. How could this be done? Is it possible to generate my `stdout.log` file `using org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` instead of `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new log file daily using log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618527/create-new-log-file-daily-using-log4j)

Comment: Yes,  you want DailyRollingFileAppender

Comment: hi thanks for your kind advice. But what I want in my log file is output of System.out/ System.err. I don't think by using DailyRollingFileAppender record the same log as ConsoleAppender. Is it possible to generate log file using org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender on daily basis?