# logs: How to print log in files using slf4j in combo with simple logger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

How to print log in files using slf4j in combo with simple logger. I am using the below jars :

slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar

I need to append a new log file for each day.

Comment: You're supposed to use only one logging backend. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at some more advanced slf4j "implementation", like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) for example (I don't think you can do that with slf4j-simple)

Answer (score 0):

hope this stackoverflow link will help, to have rolling file update: 
[Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)