# Log4j rolling file appender: include timestamp in filename

Tags: java, log4j

Starting from the current **log4j** configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/file.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
```

How could I add a date or a timestamp as part of the filename? I tried to use `RollingDateFileAppender` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j), but with no success (and also some properties like `MaxBackupIndex` and `MaxFileSize` are unsupported). Note that I would like to include a date in the format `20121102143402781` (compact) or Unix_Mills `1351866842781`.

Comment: Daily rolling appended will append timestamp when your application crosses 12:00 AM.

Comment: I would like to have always the same format, also for the first log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) dynamically

```
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();           
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"logname."+new Date().getTime(),false);
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DailyRollingFileAppender

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/file.log
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='-'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] [%t] [%c] %m%n
```

Comment: This will add the date on rolling. As far as I understood, OP wants also the current logfile to have a date. (Please correct me if wrong @vdenotaris )

Comment: I have looked the log4j API but didn't see any options

Comment: You can read this question, it's same demand with your op's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j

Answer (score -3):

I got totally excited about creating a custom Layout, but turns out PatternLayout already contains the features you need :-( You need to do something like this:

```
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern="%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss} %p %t %c - %m%n
```

%d acesses the current date, the content of the curly brackets is a [Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which you can customize to meet your needs.

Comment: OP is talking about the filename of the logfile. Not Log-Entries.