# Add datetime to log file name

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I have some logs that I want to write to a file in a spring-boot microservice.

In my "application.yml" I have the below line which is working fine. But I also want to add date and time to the file name. How do I do that?

```
logging:
  file: logs/${spring.application.name}.log
```

Ideally, I want the filename to be something like this:

```
logs/spring-boot-application_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has been answered here: [How to include date in log file's name with Spring Boot / slf4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552647/how-to-include-date-in-log-files-name-with-spring-boot-slf4j)

Basically if you want more control over the logging setup, you should have your own logback.xml under src/main/resources and configure the naming format similar to:

```
<FileNamePattern>LogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
```

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-boot , you could easily specify it in `application.yml` or `application.properties` and configuring logback xml to enable **Rolling File Appender** as :

```
spring:
logging:
  file: logs/dev_app.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger : %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    guru.springframework.controllers: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: DEBUG
```

and specify the time based rolling policy for the file in :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

  <appender name="ROLLIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLIN" />
  </root>

  <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

[Doc](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#logback-RollingTimeBased)
[Official Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Comment: @GunboldBoldsaikhan Happy to help .