# Spring boot logging file name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

Bug report ??
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiFEN.png)

```
logging:
  level:
    com.zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.kafka.test: TRACE
  file: "logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss} pid-${PID}.log"
  pattern.console: "%d{HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
```

Hello.
please help with the file name.
The time format does not work well.

I expected to see 1 file named "2020-02-07 10_38_40 pid-17996.log"

I got 2 files and the file names are bad.

Please do not advise using logback-spring.xml
I configure logs through .yml

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552647/how-to-include-date-in-log-files-name-with-spring-boot-slf4j?answertab=votes#tab-top) will answer your question.

Comment: Hi Leinarys, welcome to Stackoverflow. Some tips:    
- it is best not to attach screenshots but copy-paste the code    
- explain clearly the problem you experience then provide an example of code and configuration

Comment: @raj240 no this is not the answer