# Log file with date not generated

Tags: java, log4j

Trying to generate a log file with date.

Below is my `xml` configuration for `log4j`. From below configuration its generated only `app.log` but I am expecting `app.log.2020-3-1`.

Can someone please help me what is the issue in my configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />

        <param name="File" value="logs/app.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>   


    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your configuration is that you are using the param tag with the name DatePattern, which is not a valid parameter for the `DailyRollingFileAppender`. The correct parameter name is `fileNamePattern`, and the value should be a string that includes the pattern for the date part of the file name. For example, to create a new log file every day, you would use the following value:

```
fileNamePattern=logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

Here is the complete configuration with the correct parameter name:

```
XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM
 
"log4j.dtd">


<log4j:configuration
 
xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
 
debug="false">


    
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">

        
<param
 
name="Target"
 
value="System.out" />

        
<layout
 
class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

            
<param
 
name="ConversionPattern"
 
value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />

        
</layout>

    
</appender>


    
<appender
 
name="file"
 
class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">

        
<param
 
name="Threshold"
 
value="DEBUG" />

        
<param
 
name="append"
 
value="true" />


        
<param
 
name="File"
 
value="logs/app.log" />
        <param name="fileNamePattern" value="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

            
<param
 
name="ConversionPattern"
 
value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />

        
</layout>

    
</appender>
   


    
<root>

        
<priority
 
value="DEBUG"/>

        
<appender-ref
 
ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

With this configuration, you should now see a new log file created every day, with the date in the file name.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?